# Chaning u32 to i32 returns an error in GreetingAccount schema

Tags: solana-program

i was modifying the hello world program and trying to store/fetch an i32 value. my lib.rs  GreetingAccount struct was already updated to i32 but when i change my GreetingSchema in hello_world.ts from u32 to i32 it returns an error, does it only accepts u32 value or am i missing something? thanks in advance folks!

[image]

error message:[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `i32` is not supported by borsh-js.  If you look at the source code, it only contains writers for unsigned types, such `writeU32`.

The library needs an update to support signed types.

You can find the source code at https://github.com/near/borsh-js/blob/6db74764cedb88097bd6d5636407f0b3481fba4c/lib/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Borsh does not have support so just coerce it in your constructor assignment.